# How to make navigation bar search box wait until pressing enter in MS Access?

Tags: ms-access, search

I inherited an Access database and the main form uses the search box in the Navigation bar to find clients. The search function executes the search after every character that is entered, which is very slow over our network. There is a 2-4 second delay between each character.

Is there a way to make the search box wait until pressing "enter" before it executes the search?

I probably could add a custom search dropdown box , but I would like to avoid changing the users current practice (and save myself work) if at all possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the inbuilt search facility located down by the record selectors, you are out of luck. Its behavior is hard coded into the Access exe program.

If you build your own search function then you can control exactly how it behaves. A great example is available here; http://allenbrowne.com/ser-62.html

Comment: The database does use the inbuilt search feature. That is unfortunate that the behavior cannot be changed. I wanted to avoid building my own custom search box, but it seems inevitable.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you're not providing us with much information.
I assume your current search is executed using VBA, probably by using the OnChange event on the search box. Move that to the AfterUpdate event, and you'll be done.